# ValueError: x must be 1D

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to create a pie chart for every column and compare it between two users, and when I run my code I get the error which is:

> ValueError: x must be 1D

I am not sure what it really means, I tried to look up it but could not find anything useful, Any guidance on how can I solve this problem.
Thank you!!!!

```
# Aggregate dataframe 
summarized_df = df.groupby(['user']).agg({ 'favorite_counts': 'sum',       # Tweets overview
                                           'retweet_counts': 'sum',
                                           'is_positive': 'sum',
                                           'is_negative': 'sum',
                                          
                                           'tweets_length': 'sum',         # Tweets writing style
                                           'tweets_uppercase': 'sum',
                                           'tweets_punctuations': 'sum',
                                           'tweets_questionmark': 'sum',
                                           
                                           'is_norp': 'sum',               # Tweets detailed writing style
                                           'is_time': 'sum',
                                           'is_org': 'sum',
                                           'is_gpe': 'sum',
                                           'is_loc': 'sum',
                                           'is_product': 'sum',
                                           'is_workart': 'sum',
                                           'is_fac': 'sum',
                                           'is_noun': 'sum',
                                           'is_pron': 'sum',
                                           'is_adv': 'sum',
                                           'is_propn': 'sum',
                                           'is_verb': 'sum',
                                           'is_intj': 'sum'  }).reset_index()

# Seperate dataframe 
Tim_summarized_df = summarized_df[summarized_df.user == 'Timothy Caulfield'].drop('user', axis = 1).copy()
Keran_summarized_df = summarized_df[summarized_df.user == 'Dr. Karen James'].drop('user', axis = 1).copy()

# Get columns
summarized_cols      = Tim_summarized_df.columns

# Create features for each round in list format
round_1_cols = summarized_cols[:5]
round_2_cols = summarized_cols[5:10]
round_3_cols = summarized_cols[10:15]
round_4_cols = summarized_cols[15:20]
round_5_cols = summarized_cols[20:22]

# Combine all lists into one list
temp_list = [round_1_cols, round_2_cols, round_3_cols, round_4_cols, round_5_cols]

# Dictionary to rename the titles
rep_title_dict = {  'favorite_counts': 'Tweets Likes',
                    'retweet_counts': 'Re-Tweets',
                    'is_positive': 'Positivity',
                    'is_negative': 'Negativity',
                    'tweets_length': 'Length of Tweets',
                    'tweets_uppercase': 'Uppercase Characters Used',
                    'tweets_punctuations': 'Punctuations Used',
                    'tweets_questionmark': 'Questionmark Used',
                    'is_norp': 'Nationalities | Religious | Political Groups',
                    'is_time': 'Mentioned Time Related',
                    'is_org': 'Corporate | Governmental',
                    'is_gpe': 'Countries | Cities | States',
                    'is_loc': 'Location Mentioned',
                    'is_product': 'Objects | Vehicles | Foods',
                    'is_workart': 'Books | Songs',
                    'is_fac': 'Buildings | Airports | Highways',
                    'is_noun': 'Noun Used',
                    'is_pron': 'Pronoun Used',
                    'is_adv': 'Adverb Used',
                    'is_propn': 'Propn (like Apple, UK, US)',
                    'is_verb': 'Verb Used',
                    'is_intj': 'Bravo | Hello | Ouch' }
# Create function to plot summarized details
def summarized_donut_plot(data_1, data_2, indx_list):#, plot_title):
    
    if indx_list == 4: 
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols = 2, figsize= (13,6))
    else:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols = 5, figsize= (35,6))
        
    for indx, target in enumerate(temp_list[indx_list]):

        total = df[target].sum()
    
        # Data preproccessing
        x  = round(float(data_1[target] / total * 100), 1)
        y  = round(float(data_2[target] / total * 100), 1)

        #print(total, x, y)
        
        user_list = ['Timothy', 'Karen']
        results_list = [x, y]

        x = pd.DataFrame(data = results_list, index = user_list)

        ax[indx].pie(x, autopct='%1.1f%%', textprops = {'fontsize': 10, 'color': 'w', 'weight': 'bold'})
        ax[indx].add_patch(plt.Circle((0,0), 0.35, fc = 'white'))

        ax[indx].legend(user_list, loc = 2)
        ax[indx].set_title(rep_title_dict[target], size = 10)

    plt.show()
for indx, sublist in enumerate(temp_list):
    summarized_donut_plot( data_1 = Tim_summarized_df, 
                           data_2 = Keran_summarized_df, 
                           indx_list = indx )
```

The following is the error that I get.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [170], in <cell line: 1>()
      1 for indx, sublist in enumerate(temp_list):
----> 2     summarized_donut_plot( data_1 = Tim_summarized_df, 
      3                            data_2 = Keran_summarized_df, 
      4                            indx_list = indx )

Input In [169], in summarized_donut_plot(data_1, data_2, indx_list)
     86 results_list = [x, y]
     88 x = pd.DataFrame(data = results_list, index = user_list)
---> 90 ax[indx].pie(x, autopct='%1.1f%%', textprops = {'fontsize': 10, 'color': 'w', 'weight': 'bold'})
     91 ax[indx].add_patch(plt.Circle((0,0), 0.35, fc = 'white'))
     93 ax[indx].legend(user_list, loc = 2)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:1412, in _preprocess_data.<locals>.inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)    1409 @functools.wraps(func)    1410 def inner(ax, *args, data=None,
**kwargs):    1411     if data is None:
-> 1412         return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)    1414     bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)    1415     auto_label = (bound.arguments.get(label_namer)    1416        or bound.kwargs.get(label_namer))

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:3044, in Axes.pie(self, x, explode, labels, colors, autopct, pctdistance, shadow, labeldistance, startangle, radius, counterclock, wedgeprops, textprops, center, frame, rotatelabels, normalize)    3042 x = np.asarray(x, np.float32)    3043 if x.ndim > 1:
-> 3044     raise ValueError("x must be 1D")    3046 if np.any(x < 0):    3047     raise ValueError("Wedge sizes 'x' must be non negative values")

ValueError: x must be 1D
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1D here means 1 dimensional. When you call the pie function, x must be a 1D sequence of values. Looks to me like you're assigning a `DataFrame` to x, which is essentially a table and therefore it is 2D, even if it has only one row. If you add a `print(x.ndim)` right before calling pie it should print 2 indicating this.

I believe just replacing x with x[0] to get only the row with the data in it instead of the table should fix your error.

Comment: no problem, just don't forget to mark the answer as accepted to indicate others your issue has been solved. There should be a check mark on the left of my answer for this.